# Finding the Jacobian matrix of an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

Looking at a textbook of mine, I have noticed that there is a question I've been able to answer.

> Let f : $\mathbb{R}$ → $\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous and define I : $\mathbb{R}$ × (0,∞) → $\mathbb{R}$ by
>   I(x, t) := $\int_0^{x\over \sqrt4t}$ f(s) ds
>   Calculate the Jacobian matrix of I at (x, t) ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ × (0,∞).

I'm aware that I need to find the partial derviatives of I, but I am not sure where to start considering it's an integral. Any help to get me started would be fantastic, thanks!

EDIT: I have found the partial differentials of $ {x\over\sqrt (4t)}$ to be $\partial g\over\partial x$ = $1\over 2\sqrt t$ and $\partial g\over\partial t$ = $-x\over 4t^\frac 32$. Not sure how to proceed from here.

EDIT 2: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\int^{g(x)}_{h(x)} f(s)ds$ the derivative of $F$ is:
\begin{align}
F'(x)=g'(x) f(g(x)) - h'(x) f(h(x))
\end{align}
**Edit** Now a function with two variables:
\begin{align}
F(x,t)= \int^{g(x,t)}_{h(x,t)} f(s) ds
\end{align}
The partial derivatives:
\begin{align}
\partial_x F(x,t) = \partial_x g(x,t) f(g(x,t)) - \partial_xh(x,t) f(h(x,t))
\end{align}
And:
\begin{align}
\partial_t F(x,t) = \partial_t g(x,t) f(g(x,t)) - \partial_th(x,t) f(h(x,t))
\end{align}
Now apply this to the particular case.

Comment: Can I do the same with two variables outright??

Comment: @Zombiegit123 yes! Sure! Give it a try and add your elaboration to the question so that someone can see if it is good.

Comment: @Zombiegit123 and remember when differentiating wrt some variable then you see the other variables as a constant.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but how do I find g'(x,t)? Should I be using partial differentials? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Zombiegit123 yes! When differentiating wrt to $t$ it will be the partial derivative wrt to $t$ etc. Did this help?

Comment: Got the partial derivatives with respect to x and g, where to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: @Zombiegit123 I have edited my answer with more elaboration. The only thing that is left to do is to apply it to your specific case.

Comment: Brilliant, but how am I meant to compute this without knowing f(x,t)? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Zombiegit123 you keep it there. You do not have to do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, does it matter which element is first in the Jacobian in this case?